# Does a function have an indefinite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Does this function have an indefinite integral?

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)  & ,x \neq 0 \\ 0 & ,x=0\end{array}\right.$

Comment: $$ \int_0^x 2t\sin \tfrac{1}{t}\,dt - x^2 \sin \tfrac{1}{x} $$

Comment: Nice observation.

Comment: I guess i need to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int\limits_{0}^{x}t\sin \frac{1}{t}dt  =0$, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I have just discovered i can use L'Hôpital's rule. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sketch: Define $F(x) = \int_0^x \cos (1/t)\ dt.$ Then $F'(x) = f(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ by the FTC. To show $F'(0)= f(0)=0,$ we need to go back to the definition. So consider

$$\frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x-0} = (1/x)\int_0^x \cos (1/t)\ dt.$$

as $x\to 0^+.$ Let $t = 1/y$ to see the last integral equals

$$(1/x)\int_{1/x}^\infty \cos (y)/y^2\ dy.$$

OK, you want to show the last expression $\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+.$ I suggest integrating by parts here.

Comment: Integral $\int \cos (y)/y^2 d y$ is not elementary

Comment: True, but that's no problem. Integrate by parts and you can get an estimate that shows the expression $\to 0.$ (Although Daniel Fischer has given an easier proof.)